# Regex not working in Java code although it works on regex websites

Tags: java, regex

I guess I am just too tired, but I cannot figure it out after reading all the docs and tutorials. I have the following code:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

class Main {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    String str = "ababaaabaaaaaabbbbbbaaaaaabaabababababaaaaaabbbbbbaaaaaabababababaaaaaabbbbbbaaaaaa";
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(([ab])\2{5})(?!\1)(([ab])\4{5})(?!\3)(([ab])\6{5})");
    Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(str);

    int counter666 = 0;
    while (matcher.find()) ++counter666;
    System.out.println(counter666);
  }
}
```

I want to search the string for six occurrences of the same letter (should be a or b) three times after each other (but not three times the same letter). So, these are the only possible matches:

- "aaaaaabbbbbbaaaaaa"
- "bbbbbbaaaaaabbbbbb"

This regex is working on [regex101](https://regex101.com/) and on [this](https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html) page. However, my code always returns zero instead of three. Is there any option I have to set to make it working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're very very close. In order for the *regular expression* to work in a Java `String` you have to escape the `\` literals; otherwise the compiler doesn't put the value in the `String` (that you expect anyway). Like,

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(
        "(([ab])\\2{5})(?!\\1)(([ab])\\4{5})(?!\\3)(([ab])\\6{5})");
```

And I get (with no other changes)

```
3
```

Comment: Thank you! I totally forgot about it.

Answer (score 2):

Shorter version with less steps and two groups.

[`([ab])\1{5}(?!\1)([ab])\2{5}(?!\2)[ab]{6}`](https://regex101.com/r/olTWpF/2)